# How can I solve a problem with click on item in horizontal RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I have a horizontal recycler view. There are some buttons. I will provide my code below. So the problem is that when I click on a button, does not happen anything. It just thinks that I did not click to it. I have another recycler view, but vertical and the code is pretty similar, but the second one works. I am traying to find a mistake for ages. I really hope you can help me. Thank you.

in my main:

```
  adapter1 = new RecyclerViewAdapterContinentsList(this, idList,continentList);
            recyclerViewForContinents.setAdapter(adapter1);
            adapter1.setClickListener(new RecyclerViewAdapterContinentsList.ItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    
                }
            });
```

recyclerView class:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapterContinentsList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapterContinentsList.ViewHolder>{
    private List<String> mId;
    private List<String> mName;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;
    Context context;

    RecyclerViewAdapterContinentsList(Context context, List<String> id, List<String> name) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mId = id;
        this.mName = name;
        this.context = context;
    }

    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_recycler_view_adapter_countinent_list, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // binds the data to the TextView in each row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder,final int position) {
        String id = mId.get(position);
        String name = mName.get(position);
        holder.continentBtn.setText(name);
    }

    // total number of rows
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mName.size();
    }


    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        Button continentBtn;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            continentBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.continentBtn);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());}
        }
    }

    // convenience method for getting data at click position
    String getItem(int id) {
        return mId.get(id);
    }

    void setClickListener(RecyclerViewAdapterContinentsList.ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ViewHolder code to attach the OnClickListener to the button and not the itemView.

```
ViewHolder(View itemView) 
{
    super(itemView);
    continentBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.continentBtn);
    continentBtn.setOnClickListener(this);  // <-- button not itemView
}
```

In your ViewHolder, itemView is the root viewGroup of your layout `R.layout.activity_recycler_view_adapter_countinent_list`, a RecyclerView can listen to click events on the entire row using `setOnItemClickListener`.

Comment: Omg, it was so simple. Thanks a lot. Can you please say what means itemView in this siruation?

Answer (score 1):

It is Easy ,

First you give id in your button view Than in  your Adapter in `onBindViewHolder`

set listner in view and perform any event in listner.

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final recycler_item_ads.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.installnow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                   //here print toast
                } 
              
            }
        });
```

holfer.install now is my button in layout file